# google.oauth2 'No access token in response' error while trying to open spreadsheet

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gspread

I'm trying to open google spreadsheet via gspread, but my code fails with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/memcpy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 156, in jwt_grant
    access_token = response_data["access_token"]
KeyError: 'access_token'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email_sender.py", line 20, in <module>
    fetch_users()
  File "email_sender.py", line 16, in fetch_users
    sheet = client.open('some')

  some more tracebacks....

  File "/home/memcpy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 444, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "/home/memcpy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/home/memcpy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 359, in refresh
    access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(request, self._token_uri, assertion)
  File "/home/memcpy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 159, in jwt_grant
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('No access token in response.', {'id_token': 'there was some token so I hided it'})
```

I tried to google the error, but did not found anything about it. This is my code:

```
import gspread
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

scope = [
    'https://googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
]

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('creds.json', scopes=scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('some')
```

Comment: In your case, when the Spreadsheet ID is used like `sheet = client.open_by_key("###")`, what result will you retrieve?

Comment: did yo find the solution??

Answer (score 5):

I followed this tutorial linked here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnPlKLEGR7E&list=PLdu6wGxXWFgX9XlahY9gHEMdZ7CL5CHMY&index=5&ab_channel=TechWithTim

Make sure the scope variable is defined properly as:
scope =["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

Answer (score 1):

Pass `scope` value in list instead of string variable:

`scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/realtime-bidding']`

This solved my issue.